# Calculating next time and rounding date-time

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have datetime like 2019-02-10 20:39:23 and I want to round this time to the next one apart 15 min to the closest one. So it means the next one should be 2019-02-10 21:45:00 or another example 21:24:17 should became 21:45:00... The code below works fine until I have datetime like 2019-02-10 23:54:20. Then the next one rounded should be 2019-03-10 00:00:00 but I get 2019-02-10 00:00:00.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-10 23:54:23");

    var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

     DateTime last = NextTime(dt, interval);

     Console.WriteLine(last);

    }

    private static DateTime NextTime(DateTime value, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        var temp = value.Add(new TimeSpan(interval.Ticks / 2));
        var time = new TimeSpan((temp.TimeOfDay.Ticks / interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks);

        return value.Date.Add(time);
    }
```

For output I get 2019-02-10 00:00:00 instead of 2019-03-10 00:00:00

Can't figure out why doesn't turn to next day...

Comment: Have you tried returning temp's date + time instead of value's date: `return temp.Date.Add(time);`

Comment: @dvo yes, this is it... Thanks a lot

Comment: @RufusL sorry, my type mistake during typing question. You are right. It should be 20:45:00

Comment: @Carl900 I typed it out as an answer instead of a comment. Please mark your question as accepted. Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is being calculated from the wrong variable. Use `temp` instead of `value`:

```
 private static DateTime NextTime(DateTime value, TimeSpan interval)
 {
     var temp = value.Add(new TimeSpan(interval.Ticks / 2));
     var time = new TimeSpan((temp.TimeOfDay.Ticks / interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks);

     return temp.Date.Add(time);
 }
```

The reason for this is because you're adding your interval to the value. If it rolls over a midnight/end of day your `value.Date` will return the wrong day. Since you store `temp`, you can return `temp.Date.Add(time)`

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTime.Add(TimeSpan) the time is concat in the date.

I'v changed your code in this way and it did the trick:

```
    private static DateTime NextTime(DateTime value, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        var temp = value.Add(new TimeSpan(interval.Ticks / 2));
        var time = new TimeSpan((temp.TimeOfDay.Ticks / interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks);
        if (time == new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)) { time = new TimeSpan(24, 0,0); }
        var timeDiff = time - value.TimeOfDay;

        var finalDate = value.AddHours(timeDiff.Hours);
        finalDate = finalDate.AddMinutes(timeDiff.Minutes);
        finalDate = finalDate.AddSeconds(timeDiff.Seconds);

        return finalDate;
    }
```

I believe that must have some way more beautifull to do that but it works.

Comment: Not sure how 5 additional lines of code improves upon the accepted answer?